# Querying data from tables having one-to-many and many-to-one relationships based on the relationship

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Although I am using stackoverflow for a long time now, it's my first time posting a question. I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

I am having this database structure (please have a look at the diagram below) in SQL Server 2005 and I am now working on reports using Crystal Reports.

What I want to do is to get the total number of (count of) Courses, Facilitators, and Learners from the database for a specific Implementing Agency (which is another table not shown in this diagram, having relationship with Courses table only).

I am able to get the total number of Courses using the ImplementingAgencyID column in the where statement, but I can't figure out how to get the total number of Facilitators and Learners for the same agency (for example, ImplementingAgencyID 1 or 2).

Is there any way to do that? There are already thousands of records in the database, so even if I have to add ImplementingAgencyID column to all three tables, I won't be able to fill the this column for the old entries. It will only be added for the new entries.

Can anyone help me solve the problem? What's the best solution? I need the select query?

--- I am unable to post image, so I will list the important columns for each table below ---

```
Courses (table):
 Id         int
 SerialNum      nvarchar
 ProvinceID     int
 DistrictID     int
 VillageID      int
 EntryUserID        uniqueidentifier
 NearestSchool      nvarchar
 ImplementingAgencyID   int
 FacilitatorID
 CourseVenueID      int
 ...

Learners (table):
 Id
 CourseID
 LearnerName
 ...

Facilitators (table):
 Id
 SerialNum
 FullName
 Age
 ProvinceID
 DistrictID
 VillageID
 ...

Agencies (table):
  Id
  AgencyNameLocal
  AgencyNameEnglish
  ...
```

Relationships: 
1: ImplementingAgencyID column in Courses table has many-to-one relationship with Id column in Agencies table.

2: CourseID column in Learners table has many-to-one relationship with Id column in Courses table.

3: FacilitatorID column in Courses table has many-to-one relationship with Id column in Facilitators table.

Comment: Its better you show your real data as example (what you have and what you want to get)

Comment: What do u mean by real data? I have posted the structure and I have posted that I want the count of facilitators (Id column), learners (Id column) and courses (Id column). I am only able to get the count of courses and not the others.

Comment: Here is the diagram: http://postimg.org/image/lgxpiacxx/d39e4c46/

Comment: It isn't so easy just with database scheme help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly.
For each Agency you want to know how many of each type of unit (learner, facilitator, course) there are.

This query should do what you want to do:

```
;WITH data 
     AS (SELECT T1.*, 
                T2.FULLNAME AS Facil_Name, 
                T3.ID       AS Learner_Name, 
                T4.AGENCYNAME 
         FROM   COURSES T1 
                INNER JOIN FACILITATORS T2 
                        ON T1.FACILITATORID = t2.ID 
                INNER JOIN LEARNERS T3 
                        ON T1.ID = T3.COURSEID 
                INNER JOIN AGENCIES T4 
                        ON T1.IMPLEMENTINGAGENCYID = T4.ID) 

SELECT AGENCYNAME, 
       Count(DISTINCT FACIL_NAME) Per_Agency, 
       'Facil'                    TYPE 
FROM   data 
GROUP  BY AGENCYNAME 
UNION 
SELECT AGENCYNAME, 
       Count(DISTINCT LEARNER_NAME) Per_Agency, 
       'Learner'                    TYPE 
FROM   data 
GROUP  BY AGENCYNAME 
UNION 
SELECT AGENCYNAME, 
       Count(DISTINCT ID) Per_Agency, 
       'Course'           TYPE 
FROM   data 
GROUP  BY AGENCYNAME 
ORDER  BY TYPE
```

You can find a working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1964b/14).
Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a combination of `group by` and `count distinct`

```
select
    implementingagencyid,
    count (distinct courses.id) as CourseCount,
    count (distinct learners.id) as LearnerCount,
    count (distinct facilitators.id) as FacilitatorCount
courses
    inner join learners on courses.ID = learners.courseid
    inner join facilitators on courses.facilitatorID = facilitators.id
    inner join agencies on courses.implementingagencyid = agencies.id    
group by
    implementingagencyid
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Courses** you can count the number of rows for a certain agency (I use number 77 here):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM courses
WHERE ImplementingAgencyID = 77
```

For **Facilitators** you can count the occurences of distinct values of FacilitatorID

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FacilitatorID)
FROM courses
WHERE ImplementingAgencyID = 77
```

For **Learners** you have to join the courses and learers tables, but then you can again count the

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT l.id)
FROM courses c JOIN learners l ON c.id = l.CourseID
WHERE ImplementingAgencyID = 77
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59a68/4 to play around with.